# How do I indicate a REST API endpoint is removed

Tags: rest, http, api-design

I have an endpoint

`DELETE /events/<id>`

In the new version of the API, we are going to **remove this API**.

Now if **the client requests the same URL what status code should I output**?

I found a few options.

1. `410 Gone`. This is the closest one. But it relates to resources. **It's not about managing API**. What I think it means is, If `GET /events/1` works then it doesn't make sense to state `/events/1` is `Gone`
2. `301 Moved Permanently` and `302 Found`. They are for redirection. But the replacement is not a `GET` call
3. `405 Method Not Allowed`. It makes sense as the method `DELETE` is now allowed anymore. But it doesn't say it used to be allowed in the past(not sure if we need it)

Other http methods supported in this endpoint are,

```
GET /events/<id>/
POST /events/
POST /events/<id>/actions/
```

Just to clarify. When I google the topic I get more information about Resources. But here I'm concerned about depreciation and removal of API. It's more of a management.

Comment: If you have other HTTP methods such as GET, POST, PUT, in your endopoint /events/<id> then I believe that if you remove the DELETE method you must show "405 Method Not Allowed", if it is not the case and you dont have any http methods in that endpoint I would show 404 Not Found, or 410 Gone.

Comment: @BrankVictoria Added that in the question. You might want to add your comment as an answer.

Comment: If your API is fairly HATEOAS-compliant you could just (or additionally) stop emitting the "delete" links in the corresponding GETs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got some things twisted here.

`DELETE` is the verb and indicates a **method**, not an endpoint.

`/events` this is your endpoint.

MDN suggests `410 Gone` for resources that have been removed. Resource in a generic http context can be anything.

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 410 Gone client error response
>   code indicates that access to the target resource is no longer
>   available at the origin server and that this condition is likely to be
>   permanent.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/410

If you want to show that a method has been removed but the endpoint is still there, you would probably use `405 Method not allowed`.

You should also consider versioning the API.

Comment: The problem here is _access to the *target resource *_. It's resource-oriented. `/events/<id>` is a Resource. But `DELETE /events/<id>` is not. It's an API call.